# Create table from 2 Arrays PHP

Tags: php, simplexml

I Try to get a Table with 3 Rows in HTML. The Data comes from a XML File and i put it in an array and parse that with foreach in the table.
The problem is the Output show only one array correctly and the second array show only 1 PRICE of 5. The 5 different Prices are in the array "$recordpElements", i have check it. What im doing wrong? See the example in the Picture below.[image]

```html
public function xmlParserVB():string
  { 
        global $obj;
 
        $valuesvb = $this->xml->xpath("OBJEKT[@ID='$obj']//SAISON");
        $valuesp = $this->xml->xpath("//OBJEKT[@ID='$obj']//SAISON//PRICE");
        
        foreach (array_slice($valuesp,0,5) as $recordpElements);
        foreach (array_slice($valuesvb,0,5) as $recordvbElements)
        
         {
            $display .= '<tr>';
            $display .= '<td>'.$recordvbElements->DESCRIPTION.'</td>';
            $display .= '<td>'.$recordvbElements->FROM.' - '.$recordvbElements->UNTIL.'</td>';
            $display .= '<td>'.$recordpElements->PRICE.' &euro;</td>';
            $display .= '</tr>';
        
    
        }
        
     $display .= '';

      return $display;
        
  }
```

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your 5th line of code.

```
foreach (array_slice($valuesp,0,5) as $recordpElements);
```

if you run this code then you will get last record of `array_slice($valuesp,0,5)` in `$recordpElements`

So.. you will get the 5th record of `$valuesp` array in your `$recordpElements`.

I don't understand why the price array(`$valuesp`) and product array(`$valuesvb`) should exist separately, but assuming that's correct, if the product sequence and price sequence match, you should try something like this:

```
        $price = array_slice($valuesp,0,5);
        $index = 0;
        foreach (array_slice($valuesvb,0,5) as $recordvbElements)
        {

            $display .= '<tr>';
            $display .= '<td>'.$recordvbElements->DESCRIPTION.'</td>';
            $display .= '<td>'.$recordvbElements->FROM.' - '.$recordvbElements->UNTIL.'</td>';
            $display .= '<td>'.$price[$index]->PRICE.' &euro;</td>';
            $display .= '</tr>';
        
           $index++;
        }
```

Comment: If i run that code foreach (array_slice($valuesp,0,5) as $recordpElements); i get the first 5 elements from my array

Comment: `array_slice($valuesp,0,5)` is get first 5 element, but if you run `foreach(..... as $recordpElements);`  then you will get last element of 5 elements($valuesp) in `$recordpElement` variable. after then you are using $recordpElements. so your all of price will 5th price of array.

Comment: Sorry i forgot a Letter in my code. Now it work fine. Many Thanks to the Smart Guy SILVERSTAR.